# How to properly generate distance map?

Tags: qgis, distance, proximity, gdal-proximity

This question is a related to [Proximity (raster distance) using ellipsoidal distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/418818/proximity-raster-distance-using-ellipsoidal-distance)

What I'm trying to do is to generate a map of distances to roads. At any given point on a map, I want to be able to instantly say: "you are X kilometres away from a main road".

So my initial thoughts were, get road information from OSM, or draw them, and generate a distance map using `Raster -> Analysis -> Proximity (Raster Distance)` (after rasterizing that road vector layer).

The problem however seems to be that the Proximity algorithm isn't aware of any CRS. It simply calculates the distances naively without any transformation. Consider the following trivial example

[image: a long road]

That's one long road all the way from Africa to Russia in one "straight" line (at least on the map). I rasterized this road and then used the Proximity tool with a cut-off of 500 km, and georeferenced coordinates, and this is what I got:

[image: ![enter image description here]

So clearly this tool does not take into account any stretching of the map. Which results in a straight line with a uniform distance gradient. This means that depending on the position on the map, the sampled distance on the proximity layer is reasonably correct near the equator and completely off the more north or south you go. Which obviously makes sense if the generated distance map is based on Cartesian calculations and not ellipsoid calculations.

Is there any way for me to warp, transform or modify this distance map so that it more closely resembles the CRS I'm using (EPSG:3857)?  Accuracy isn't a big problem; it's okay to be a few hundred meters off. As long as I'm able to process the road network of the large portion of the Earth in one go, I'm very happy.

Comment: Did you try to run the analysis with project and layer CRS set to a CRS more accurate for your task? You could then reproject the resulting raster back to `EPSG:3857` if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those battling the same issue in the future: I came up with a new solution, that I [posted on GitHub](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/46509).

`TL;DR`: This is the code

https://gist.github.com/MarByteBeep/e688759bc051a59a5651e0ecd45240ff

The long read:

Based on work done by [Spatial Thoughts](https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/05/geodesic-buffers-in-qgis) I created a simple algorithm that iteratively created new features and stores the distance to the original feature in a `BURN` field. These distances are calculated using Azimuthal Equidistant projection. These new features can then be used to create a more accurate proximity map.

Let me provide an example. Consider the following features (military objects around some local town)

[image]

Next I run the proximity script, with the following settings

`Buffer Distance` specifies the distance the buffer is drawn around a feature. In this case I defined a distance of 5000 meters.

`Segments` specifies how well curves are approximated. Lower is more jaggy.

`Iterations` specifies how many iso-distances are generated.

`Rasterize render resolution` specifies the rasterizer resolution in degrees.

You can deselect `Open output file after running algorithm` of the `Proximity Vector layer`, as that layer is mostly an intermediate layer. But for the sake of explaining what's going on I'll leave it switched on.

[image]

When hitting run two layers, `Proximity Vector layer` and `Rasterized`, are generated.

First let's focus on the `Proximity Vector layer`:

[image]

When inspecting one of the structures, you can see that all rings contain different `BURN` values, each representing the distance to the original feature. Obviously I could also have named the field: `DISTANCE`. But whatever :)

[image]

The other layer `Rasterize` is the one we're after:

[image]

When sampling this layer, the value in the band will represent the distance in meters.

[image]

Code available below as a GitHub gist. Any optimization suggestions or other ideas are more than welcome!

https://gist.github.com/MarByteBeep/e688759bc051a59a5651e0ecd45240ff

After running 'the long road' example posted in the original question with the new algorithm, I ended up with something more intuitively correct:

[image: the long road]

Comment: I don't think that this solution really returns real world distances. EPSG:4326 is not good to measure distances, either.

Comment: I think you are right. I just found that out. Back to square one. I feel I first need to take a few steps back and get into the details of projections... It's interesting though, you would expect someone else made a distance map of say roads, or airports all across the globe. Question is: how to do that... easily :)

Comment: For a start, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148181/choosing-projection-crs-for-short-distance-based-analysis/148187 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375725/appropriate-crs-for-close-distances-in-usa

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: Creating geodesic buffers might be what you want to do, see: https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/05/geodesic-buffers-in-qgis/

Comment: That indeed seems to generate a buffer with the correct distance around a feature. Awesome. Now the 'only' thing left would be to see if it is possible to create a gradient containing the distance information in it. Or I need to modify the script in such a way that it generates multiple buffers, each a bit larger than the previous one and then somehow combine that information in it... Either way, it would've been great if the proximity tool would be able to use this method.

Comment: @babel I created a new script based on the idea you posted. Code and explanation is available here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/46509

Comment: That's great: thanks for the link!

Comment: Maybe worth extending your solution by adding the most important info from your GitHub post?

Comment: Done that. Thanks for the suggestion